# How to subclass CompletableFuture?

Tags: java, java-8, future

I'd like to subclass [CompletableFuture](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html) to override the default `Executor`. That is, if a user invokes a method without specifying an `Executor`, I want my own `Executor` to get used instead of the one normally used by `CompletableFuture`.

The Javadoc hints at the possibility of subclassing:

> All CompletionStage methods are implemented independently of other public methods, so the behavior of one method is not impacted by overrides of others in subclasses.

How am I supposed to implement static methods like `CompletableFuture.supplyAsync()` in the subclass if the underlying implementation depends on methods like `internalComplete()` which is package-private?

**How is one supposed to subclass CompletableFuture?**

---

### What I'm trying to do...

My user code needs to execute multiple tasks asynchronously using the same executor. For example: `CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(..., executor).thenApplyAsync(..., executor).thenApplyAsync(..., executor)`. I'd like the custom `CompletableFuture` implementation to use the first executor throughout all follow-up calls.

Comment: You can’t “implement static methods”; that’s impossible. I doubt that you are “supposed to subclass `CompletableFuture`” at all. The hint you have cited only tells me, how hard subclassing would be as you have to override *all* overloads to ensure modified behavior. But of course, you can’t alter the behavior of `static` methods by subclassing. It would be pointless anyway; if the caller of a `static` method wants to use a subclass instead, the caller can simply call a method of the subclass instead. But Java code using the base class will never be affected by the mere existence of a subclass.

Comment: The CompletableFuture docs *do* refer to subclasses.

Comment: @chrispy, updated question with use-case.

Comment: I think CompletableFuture is too unwieldy to be used directly in applications. Shameless plug, see my Async API for java8 - http://bayou.io/release/0.9/docs/async/Async_Programming.html

Comment: What is the point to call your functions this way? Since each stage waits for the result of the previous stage, all functions are executed serially, not in parallel. Just call f3(f1(f0))).

Comment: @AlexeiKaigorodov, I am intentionally introducing a delay between each call. I am hitting a rate-limiting web service and need to respect its limits.

Comment: but I cannot see delays in your code. Do you make delays in your custom Executor?

Comment: @AlexeiKaigorodov, yes. My custom `Executor`delegates to `ScheduledExecutorService`, scheduling the task to run at some future time.

Comment: I still don’t get your question. If you want to create a subclass of `CompletableFuture` overriding `thenApplyAsync`, then just do it. Why do you bother with how the `static` method `supplyAsync` works internally?

Comment: @chrispy: so it’s just a typical “failed to show what he tried” thing, maybe a simple mistake in his source code?

Comment: Judging from the message ['Candidate jdk9 CompletableFuture additions'](http://cs.oswego.edu/pipermail/concurrency-interest/2015-January/013600.html) posted to the concurrency-interest mailing list, it seems that the authors of `CompletableFuture` agree that it should be easier to extend it. Looks like the proposed new methods `newIncompleteFuture` and `defaultExecutor` might help to resolve this question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Starting with Java 9, there is built-in support for this task:

```java
public class MyCompletableFuture<T> extends CompletableFuture<T> {

    public static <T> CompletableFuture<T> supplyAsync(Supplier<T> s, Executor e) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(s);
        Objects.requireNonNull(e);
        return new MyCompletableFuture<T>(e).completeAsync(s);
    }

    private final Executor executor;

    public MyCompletableFuture(Executor executor) {
        this.executor = executor;
    }

    @Override
    public <U> CompletableFuture<U> newIncompleteFuture() {
        return new MyCompletableFuture<>(executor);
    }

    @Override
    public Executor defaultExecutor() {
        return executor;
    }
}
```

- By overriding `newIncompleteFuture()`, we can ensure that all `then…` and `when…`, etc. methods will return instances of `MyCompletableFuture`, without overriding each of them.
- The `defaultExecutor()` method specifies the executor to be used by all async methods without `Executor` parameter.
- Conveniently, the non-`static` method `completeAsync` allows us to get the `supplyAsync` behavior using an instance of our future implementation. The example above provides a `static` method `supplyAsync` which can be used similarly to the original one, i.e. `MyCompletableFuture.supplyAsync(supplier, executor)`

---

In Java 8, you have to override all methods whose behavior you want to alter, using the decoration pattern, which still doesn’t need to touch any of the `CompletableFuture`’s inner workings.

```
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.util.function.*;

public class MyCompletableFuture<T> extends CompletableFuture<T> {
    public static <T> CompletableFuture<T> supplyAsync(Supplier<T> s, Executor e){
        return my(CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(s, e), e);
    }
    private static <T> CompletableFuture<T> my(CompletableFuture<T> f,Executor e){
        MyCompletableFuture<T> my=new MyCompletableFuture<>(f, e);
        f.whenComplete((v,t)-> {
            if(t!=null) my.completeExceptionally(t); else my.complete(v);
        });
        return my;
    }
    private final CompletableFuture<T> baseFuture;
    private final Executor executor;

    MyCompletableFuture(CompletableFuture<T> base, Executor e) {
        baseFuture=base;
        executor=e;
    }
    private <T> CompletableFuture<T> my(CompletableFuture<T> base) {
        return my(base, executor);
    }
    @Override
    public CompletableFuture<Void> acceptEitherAsync(
            CompletionStage<? extends T> other, Consumer<? super T> action) {
        return my(baseFuture.acceptEitherAsync(other, action, executor));
    }
    @Override
    public <U> CompletableFuture<U> applyToEitherAsync(
            CompletionStage<? extends T> other, Function<? super T, U> fn) {
        return my(baseFuture.applyToEitherAsync(other, fn, executor));
    }
    @Override
    public <U> CompletableFuture<U> handleAsync(
            BiFunction<? super T, Throwable, ? extends U> fn) {
        return my(baseFuture.handleAsync(fn, executor));
    }
    @Override
    public CompletableFuture<Void> runAfterBothAsync(
            CompletionStage<?> other, Runnable action) {
        return my(baseFuture.runAfterBothAsync(other, action, executor));
    }
    @Override
    public CompletableFuture<Void> runAfterEitherAsync(
            CompletionStage<?> other, Runnable action) {
        return my(baseFuture.runAfterEitherAsync(other, action, executor));
    }
    @Override
    public CompletableFuture<Void> thenAcceptAsync(Consumer<? super T> action) {
        return my(baseFuture.thenAcceptAsync(action, executor));
    }
    @Override
    public <U> CompletableFuture<Void> thenAcceptBothAsync(
            CompletionStage<? extends U> other,
            BiConsumer<? super T, ? super U> action) {
        return my(baseFuture.thenAcceptBothAsync(other, action, executor));
    }
    @Override
    public <U> CompletableFuture<U> thenApplyAsync(
            Function<? super T, ? extends U> fn) {
        return my(baseFuture.thenApplyAsync(fn, executor));
    }
    @Override
    public <U, V> CompletableFuture<V> thenCombineAsync(
            CompletionStage<? extends U> other,
            BiFunction<? super T, ? super U, ? extends V> fn) {
        return my(baseFuture.thenCombineAsync(other, fn, executor));
    }
    @Override
    public <U> CompletableFuture<U> thenComposeAsync(
            Function<? super T, ? extends CompletionStage<U>> fn) {
        return my(baseFuture.thenComposeAsync(fn, executor));
    }
    @Override
    public CompletableFuture<Void> thenRunAsync(Runnable action) {
        return my(baseFuture.thenRunAsync(action, executor));
    }
    @Override
    public CompletableFuture<T> whenCompleteAsync(
            BiConsumer<? super T, ? super Throwable> action) {
        return my(baseFuture.whenCompleteAsync(action, executor));
    }
}
```

Here is a simple test case which shows that it works as expected:

```
ScheduledExecutorService ses=Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
Executor e=r -> {
    System.out.println("adding delay");
    ses.schedule(r, 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
};
MyCompletableFuture.supplyAsync(()->"initial value", e)
  .thenApplyAsync(String::hashCode)
  .thenApplyAsync(Integer::toOctalString)
  .thenAcceptAsync(System.out::println);
```

Comment: You are right. I was in the process of putting together a minimal testcase when I discovered what was wrong with my code. The `CompletableFuture` was being scheduled on a custom Executor. That `Executor` scheduled each task's start time relative to the end time of the previous task. It turns out that `thenComposeAsync()` blocks the outer task until the inner task finishes executing. So `CompletableFuture` was waiting on the `Executor` to run the inner task, and the `Executor` was waiting on the `CompletableFuture` to finish running the inner task. Thank you for your help!

Comment: I am trying to figure out how to use a PriorityBlockingQueue for the executor used by CompletableFuture.supplyAsync, but it doesn't look like your subclass example addresses that scenario. The problem is that supplyAsync wraps the Supplier in a private inner class implementation of a Runnable that is then passed to the Comparator of the priority queue. It seems that subclassing that functionality is much more complicated due to its private encapsulation.

Answer (score 1):

Answering the original question -- **How is one supposed to subclass CompletableFuture?**

Probably starting from a clean-room CompletionStage interface implementation (rather than from the concrete CompletableFuture class) a  is a better option. Please take a look here:

https://github.com/lukas-krecan/completion-stage

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, you need your own implementation of `internalComplete()` which instantiates your own equivalent of `AltResult` in case of null or exception. And your subclass `supplyAsync()` is supposed to return a new instance of your new `CompletableFuture` subclass.

Comment: `internalComplete()` accesses private variable `CompletableFuture.RESULT`, so it's not enough to instantiate the equivalent of `AltResult`.

Answer (score 0):

Your goal is to limit the rate of access to the web service. Your solution is to use special executor which introduces delays. This is not the best solution, because some function in the chain can spend some time for other activity, or just wait too long in the queue to processor on O/S level and thus need not be delayed before accessing the web service, but will be delayed by the executor anyway. Delays should be embedded in the module which actually performs requests to the web service. It should remember the time of the previous request and, if it is too small, just call Thread.sleep() before sending request via socket. This way you need not any CompletableFuture and can call functions directly like f3(f1(f0))). At least it is more readable.

Comment: My application is hitting someone else's remote web service. The delays are client-side, not server-side. Delays are quite large (5-10 seconds).

Comment: yes, client side. Probably it was a bad choice of words on my part: saying "performs requests" I mean "sends requests and receives replies".

Answer (score -3):

Async programming is widely misunderstood. Theoretical approach is to represent async program as Petri net, where main components are tokens, places, and transitions. From programming point of view, transition should be split further into firing rule and action. Logical chain appears to be too long, programmers prefer oversimplified scheme "event-reaction", which does not work in any complex cases. CompletableFuture  is even more restricted, with scheme "action - primitive transition - action".

In your case, each stage has to be feed from two sources: result of previous stage and resource token allowing to access the web service. CompletableFuture simply does not fit for such cases. I would recommend first draw the Petri net for your case, and then implement basic infrastructure from scratch, using classes with synchronized methods. Or try my async library  [df4j2](https://github.com/rfqu/df4j2), which allows to build transitions with several places.

Comment: Sorry, but this does not actually answer my question. There are many async libraries out there, and while I'm sure they are all great I am asking a specific question about `CompletableFuture`.